# How to send class instance through sockets?

Tags: c#, class, sockets, instance

I've run into a problem with sockets.
I need to pass an instance of a Message class through socket to a server. Is there any way to do so?

**Message class**

```cs
class Message
    {
        private Socket client;
        private string message;

        public Message(Socket client, string message)
        {
            this.client = client;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public async Task<Message> AcceptMessage()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

**Your Implementation**

```
public async Task RegisterClient() 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var clientSocket = await this.socket.AcceptAsync();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int size = 0;
            StringBuilder username = new StringBuilder();

            size = await clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer);  //Here I need to get a message instance. 
            username.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, size)); // Now its just string

            Client client = new Client(clientSocket, username.ToString());
            this.clients.Add(client);

            this.Notify(new Message(this, $"User has joined: {client.Username}"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to decide on a serialization strategy. JSON, for example, is used a lot these days, but you could also develop a custom binary scheme, or use protobuf, or similar.